# How to Send mail using amazon web services from android application

Tags: android, email, sendmail, amazon-ses

I found some information in amazon webservices for sending mail from android application.It contains the following code.How to use this code in my application.Please help me.

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials( PropertyLoader.getInstance().getAccessKey(), PropertyLoader.getInstance().getSecretKey() );
    AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);
    String subjectText = "Feedback from " + nameField.getText();
    Content subjectContent = new Content(subjectText);
    String bodyText = "Rating: " + ratingBar.getRating() + "\nComments\n" + commentsField.getText();
    Body messageBody = new Body(new Content(bodyText));
    Message feedbackMessage = new Message(subjectContent,messageBody);
    String email = PropertyLoader.getInstance().getVerifiedEmail();
    Destination destination = new Destination().withToAddresses(email);
    SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest(email,destination,feedbackMessage);
    SendEmailResult result = clientManager.ses().sendEmail(request);
```

Comment: I downloaded AWS sdk-ses for android  which consists of  more than 40 files and i tried to integrate them .But there are so many errors while integrating it.Please help me Andriy